# Rails 4 - Form conditional, check model attribute bool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for a model Bid. I have two attributes :attribute and :is_attribute. I only want to show :attribute in the update form if :is_attribute is true. How can I check :is_attribute?

I've tried

```
<% if @bid.is_attribute %>
  <%= f.label :attribute %>
  <%= f.text_area :attribute %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% if f.object.is_attribute %>
  <%= f.label :attribute %>
  <%= f.text_area :attribute %>
<% end %>
```

Neither are allowing the field to show up at all, even when it should. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you update the question with the full conditional (i.e. including all between if and end)

Comment: You may be running into a Ruby reserved word. Code would be helpful.

Comment: OK, thanks. It should work as it is. I'm gona bet that `@bid.is_attribute` is nil or false. How do you knwo that the fields are to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use `is_attribute?` to check the boolean value of is_attribute:

```
<% if @bid.is_attribute? %>
    .... show content ....
<% end %>
```